# Order of growth or hierarchy between different mathematical functions

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, subgroup-growth

I am trying to find a demonstration to find the exact order with respect to the order of growth between the following functions:

$2^n-a^n-n^n-n!$

I first know that the smallest function expression will probably be n!, due to it is a product which factors are decreasing
$n!=n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * 2 * 1$

However, in order to compute the difference or the order of growth between $2^n, a^n,n^n$ I have tried to compute the $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^n}{a^n}$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a^n}{2^n}$ but I cannot solve it.

Comment: Take their log. E.g. $\log(n^n/a^n)=n(\log n-\log a)\to\infty$

Comment: @AnneBauval but what about $a^n$ and $2^n$

Comment: Do the same and discuss, depending whether $a$ >/</= $2$.